# this code does not switch to the second while code when the condition is met, how do i fix this?

Tags: c++, while-loop

this is where it starts

```
//
//  main.cpp
//  work ing test
//
//  Created by has on 5/4/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 has. All rights reserved.
//

#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;
```

these are the functions i am using, there may be a problem with them.

```
int economy(int plane[], int count){
    int seat = 0;
    seat = count+1;
    return seat;
}
int place(int plane[],int count){
    int seat = 0;
    seat = count+1;

    return seat;
}
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int count; int plane[10]={}, seat, ticket;
    cout<< " enter the class you want 1 for first, 2 for economy, 3 for none"<<endl;
    cin>>ticket;
```

first while statement

```
    while(ticket==1)
    {
        for (count=0; count < 5; count++)
        {
            if(plane[count] == 0)
            {
                seat=place(&plane[count], count);
                cout<<"$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$"<<endl;
                cout<<"$ you are first class"<<endl;
                cout<<"$ this is your seat number for the flight "<< seat<<endl;
                cout<<"$ have a nice flight and thank you for flying with POINT AIR"<<endl;
                cout<<"$ the safest way to a point"<<endl;
                cout<<"$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$"<<endl;
                plane[count]=1;
                cout<< " enter the class you want 1 for first, 2 for economy, 3 for none"<<endl;
                cin>>ticket;        }
        }
        if(plane[4]!=0)
        {
            cout<< " the first calss seats are all booked, we may have secondary class avabile would like to try it, press 2 for secondary class, press 3 for none."<<endl;
            cin>>ticket;
        }
    }
```

second while statement

```
    while(ticket==2)
    {
        for (count=4; count < 10; count++)
        {
            if(plane[count] == 0)
            {
                seat=economy(&plane[count], count);
                cout<<"******************************************************************"<<endl;
                cout<<"* you are economy class"<<endl;
                cout<<"* this is your seat number for the flight "<< seat<<endl;
                cout<<"* have a nice flight, and thank you for flying with POINT AIR"<<endl;
                cout<<"* the safest way to a point"<<endl;
                cout<<"******************************************************************"<<endl;
                plane[count]=1;
                cout<< " enter the class you want to buy a seat with 1 for first, 2 for economy, 3 for none"<<endl;
                cin>>ticket;        }
        }
        if(plane[9]!=0)
        {
            cout<< " the economy calss seats are all booked, we may have first class avabile would like to try it, press 1 for first class, press 3 for none."<<endl;
            cin>>ticket;
        }
    }
    while (ticket==3) {
        cout<<" the next flight leaves in 3 hours"<<endl;
        cout<<" if you would like to purchase a ticket press one of the following or press 4 to exit."<<endl;
        cout<<" press 1 for first class, 2 for economy class, or 3 to know what time the flight leaves"<<endl;
        cin>>ticket;
    }
    while (ticket==4) {
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the output is when i press 2, it should say what the second while loop should have said not the first.

```
enter the class you want 1 for first, 2 for economy, 3 for none
1
$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
$ you are first class
$ this is your seat number for the flight 1
$ have a nice flight and thank you for flying with POINT AIR
$ the safest way to a point
$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
 enter the class you want 1 for first, 2 for economy, 3 for none
2
$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
$ you are first class
$ this is your seat number for the flight 2
$ have a nice flight and thank you for flying with POINT AIR
$ the safest way to a point
$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
 enter the class you want 1 for first, 2 for economy, 3 for none
```

to hussan this is what i did with your pusedo code

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;
int economy(int plane[], int count){
    int seat = 0;
    seat = count+1;
    return seat;
}
int place(int plane[],int count){
    int seat = 0;
    seat = count+1;

    return seat;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int count; int plane[10]={}, seat, ticket;
    do
    {
        cout<< " enter the class you want 1 for first, 2 for economy, 3 for none"<<endl;
        cin>>ticket;
        if(ticket == 1)
        { for (count=0; count < 5; count++)
        {
            if(plane[count] == 0)
            {
                seat=place(&plane[count], count);
                cout<<"$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$"<<endl;
                cout<<"$ you are first class"<<endl;
                cout<<"$ this is your seat number for the flight "<< seat<<endl;
                cout<<"$ have a nice flight and thank you for flying with POINT AIR"<<endl;
                cout<<"$ the safest way to a point"<<endl;
                cout<<"$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$"<<endl;
                plane[count]=1;
                cout<< " enter the class you want 1 for first, 2 for economy, 3 for none"<<endl;
                cin>>ticket;
            }
            if(plane[4]!=0)
            {
                cout<< " the first calss seats are all booked, we may have secondary class avabile would like to try it, press 2 for secondary class, press 3 for none."<<endl;
                cin>>ticket;}
        }
        }

            else if(ticket == 2)
            { for (count=4; count < 10; count++)
            {
                if(plane[count] == 0)
                {
                    seat=economy(&plane[count], count);
                    cout<<"******************************************************************"<<endl;
                    cout<<"* you are economy class"<<endl;
                    cout<<"* this is your seat number for the flight "<< seat<<endl;
                    cout<<"* have a nice flight, and thank you for flying with POINT AIR"<<endl;
                    cout<<"* the safest way to a point"<<endl;
                    cout<<"******************************************************************"<<endl;
                    plane[count]=1;
                    cout<< " enter the class you want to buy a seat with 1 for first, 2 for economy, 3 for none"<<endl;
                    cin>>ticket;

                }
            }
                if(plane[9]!=0)
                {
                    cout<< " the economy calss seats are all booked, we may have first class avabile would like to try it, press 1 for first class, press 3 for none."<<endl;
                    cin>>ticket;
                }
}
                else if(ticket == 3)
                {
                    cout<<" the next flight leaves in 3 hours"<<endl;
                    cout<<" if you would like to purchase a ticket press one of the following or press 4 to exit."<<endl;
                    cout<<" press 1 for first class, 2 for economy class, or 3 to know what time the flight leaves"<<endl;
                    cin>>ticket;
}
        else if(ticket == 4)
        {
            return 0;
        }
                    else break;


                }while(true);
    return 0;
                    }
```

Comment: I suggest that you include some print statements that tell you what the value of `ticket` is at various points in the program - maybe even step through with a debugger. There is a lot you could do to make the flow more logical - one place for input, then handle different cases in a switch statement, for example. Your current `while` structure means that once someone has booked a second class ticket they cannot then book a first class, for example.

Comment: should i place the cout statement that asks again outside of the while loop

Comment: Instead of repeating `cout<< " enter the class....` everywhere, you should instead do `continue;` - this will jump back up to the first line after the `do {`.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using while everywhere? Once a while loop is entered, it will not enter in any previous loop. Your code should be like this (pseudo):

```
do
{
  cout<< " enter the class you want 1 for first, 2 for economy, 3 for none"<<endl;
  cin>>ticket;
  if(ticket == 1) { /*do staff for ticket type 1*/}
  else if(ticket == 2) { /*do staff for ticket type 1*/}
  else if(ticket == 3) { /*do staff for ticket type 1*/}
  else break; // end loop when ticket is 4


}while(true)
```

Edit:

The logic is to you check user choice of ticket and process the request until some condition is met. The ending condition here is ticket type 3 (or 4 may be). So you check input and process the request until user enters 3/4;

```
 do
 {
   //get  ticket type and process
 }until type is 3
```

In your original code you were using `while` every where. So if user first enters 2 and u process request, then enters 1,  the function will just end. Because there is no way to go to the upper loop.

Comment: i tried that and it did not work. it gave me the same problem again

Comment: i tried that i literally copied my code into the brackets and it still gave me the same thing....

Comment: I did not understand your last comment. But what is important most is "did you get the logical error of your code"?

Comment: Check edit. You should first learn about looping constructs ( for/while/do-while) and how they works

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that is structured to handle different inputs, including a "bad" input (non integer).

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

int main(void) {
  bool keepGoing;
  int ticket;
  int economyAvailable = 6, firstAvailable = 4; // small plane
  keepGoing = true;
  while(keepGoing) {
    cout << "What ticket do you want? 1 = first, 2 = economy, 3 = quit"<<endl;
    cin >> ticket;
    switch(ticket) {
    case 1:
      if(firstAvailable>0) {
        firstAvailable--;
        cout << "I found you a seat!" << endl;
        break;
      }
      else {
        cout << "I am sorry, first class is sold out" << endl;
        cout << "I will check economy class for you" << endl;
      }
      // and now you "fall through" to the next case:
    case 2:
      if(economyAvailable > 0) {
        cout << "I found you an economy class seat" << endl;
        economyAvailable--;
      }
      else {
        cout << "I am sorry, economy class is sold out" << endl;
      }
      break;
    case 3:
      cout << "Goodbye!" << endl;
      keepGoing = false;
      break;
    default:
      cin.clear(); // clear error... in case a letter is typed etc.
      cin.ignore();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i dont get the keepgoing, is it the variable that makes my function keep going or is it a new variable that i should add.

Comment: @user3600306 - `keepGoing` is a boolean variable I introduced; this kind of variable is sometimes called a "flag" and it allows you to change the behavior of an outer loop from "deep inside an inner loop". I ran the above code and it works- it keeps prompting until you type a 3, then it stops. Right now it doesn't check for inputs other than 3 - for this you can add a `default: break;` case. You might also consider what happens if the user enters something that isn't a number... input/error checking is an important part of writing "solid" code.

Comment: i copied and pasted my for loop with its inner if loops into the code and it did not work

Comment: That's the problem... there is a lot wrong with your inner code. Let me make a more extensive example.